# How can find an update value and move it to the beginning of array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array. I want to change the value and find it then put the change value to beginning of array

```js
var item = {...}
var items = [{id:2}, {id:2}, {id:2}];

var foundIndex = items.findIndex(x => x.id == item.id);
items[foundIndex] = item;
```

Comment: You have the same object 3 times in the list, are you updating by index?

Answer (score 1):

Find it splice it unshift it.

```js
var arr = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
var find = 6;


arr.unshift(arr.splice(arr.indexOf(find), 1))
console.log("" + arr)
```